# Installation of R under Redhat el6

Tags: r

I'm trying to install R under redhat el6, and I'm having a very difficult time. I wanted to ask if anybody had installed R under redhat and wanted to share any lesson learned.

Thank you/.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the epel repos and use the pre-built rpm versions.

The [R FAQ, Section 2.6 on Unix Binaries for R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Are-there-Unix_002dlike-binaries-for-R_003f) has this to say on the topic:

> R binaries for Fedora, maintained by Tom “Spot” Callaway, are provided
>   as part of the Fedora distribution and can be accessed through yum,
>   the RPM installer/updater. The Fedora R RPM is a “meta-package” which
>   installs all the user and developer components of R (available
>   separately as R-core and R-devel), as well as the standalone R math
>   library (libRmath and libRmath-devel). RPMs for a selection of R
>   packages are also provided by Fedora. The Extra Packages for
>   Enterprise Linux (EPEL) project (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)
>   provides ports of the Fedora RPMs for RedHat Enterprise Linux and
>   compatible distributions. When a new version of R is released, there
>   may be a delay of up to 2 weeks until the Fedora RPM becomes publicly
>   available, as it must pass through the statutory Fedora review
>   process.

Comment: I installed EPEL, but now I get the following:

Comment: ---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:2.15.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: texinfo-tex for package: R-devel-2.15.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package texlive-texmf-errata-dvips.noarch 0:2007-7.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package texlive-texmf-errata-fonts.noarch 0:2007-7.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-devel-2.15.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest